# Is it possible to handle columns as rows type design with an ORM?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, nhibernate

I have a situation wherein to accomodate the need of dynamic addition of columns to a table, I am putting the columns values as rows in a table.
As an example, storing of columns of an Address Table would be in the format:

```
ID    PropertyName
1     HouseNo.
2     Street
3     City
4     State
5     Country
```

Now, if I need to create an ORM for such kind of table design in code, does LINQ2SQL, NHibernate or Entity framework provide a way for handling this?
Or what would be the most suitable way to deal with this kind of model? Manually creating business classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate can achieve something similar using the `<dynamic-component>` mapping, have a look at [this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/11/nhibernate-mapping-ltdynamic-componentgt.aspx) for more details.

**Update:**

Although somewhat similar to what you were asking about, the `<dynamic-component>` doesn't really achieve your goals; what you should *actually* be looking at is the `<map>` mapping, that's described [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx).